# UI not updating after userReducer changes state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I`m trying to use a reducer function to update state. I have a state variable, phones, which is an array of phone objects. When the user clicks a button, I want the quantity property of the phone object to increase. Quantity does get increased, but there's no change in the UI.

Here`s my code:

```
const initialState = {
  phones: [...Phones]
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "increase") {
    const newPhones = state.phones.map(phone => {
      if (phone.id === action.payload) {
        return { ...phone, quantity: phone.quantity + 1 };
      }
      return phone;
    });
    return { ...state, phones: newPhones };
  }
};

const Cart = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <div className="cart_div">
      <h1>Your Bag</h1>
      {Phones.map(phone =>
        <PhoneListItem
          key={phone.id}
          dispatch={dispatch}
          state={state}
          {...phone}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const PhoneListItem = ({ name, price, img, quantity, dispatch, id, state}) => {

  return (
    <div className="phone_row">
      <img className="phone_img" src={img} />
      <div className="phone_info_div">
        <h4>
          {name}
        </h4>
        <h4 className="price">
          {price}
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div className="phone_amount_div">
        //user clicks on button to increase phone quantity
        <button className="increase_button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increase", payload: id })}>
          <Icon icon="akar-icons:chevron-up" />
        </button>
        <p className="phone_amount_para">{quantity}</p>
        <button className="decrease_button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrease", payload: id })}>
          <Icon icon="akar-icons:chevron-down" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: In `Cart` try changing `{Phones.map(phone =>` to `{state.phones.map(phone =>`

Comment: wow it works now, but why

Comment: because `Phones` is a variable declared or imported from outside the component and is never updated, whereas `state.phones` is the value returned from the `useReducer` hook that actually gets updated when you dispatch the event.

Answer (score 0):

[useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) will return the **whole** state instead of a state slice.

You already get the state by array destructuring, but you didn't use it.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

{state.Phones.map(phone => {
  return <PhoneListItem
          key={phone.id}
          dispatch={dispatch}
          state={state}
          {...phone}
        />
})}
```